# How to extract interface names of brlan0 from brctl output with bash

Tags: bash

How can I get the interfaces of brlan0? I tried `brctl show | grep brlan0`, but I only got ath0.
The correct result should be ath0, ath1.

[image]

```
brlan0    8000.0050f122ffff    no    ath0
                                     ath1
```

Comment: Please post the image content as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT: My original answer was trash, as I was rushing to be first]**

Try this:

```sh
brctl show \
  | perl -p00e 's/\n\s+(?=\w)/,/g' \
  | grep -P '^brlan0\b' \
  | awk '{print $NF}'
```

#### Explanation

1. First, the `perl` pipe merges all hanging indentations into their preceding line:

   - For the command options:

     1. `p` sets the print flag.
     2. `00` sets the null byte/character to allow proper multi-line processing.
     3. `e` is the execution flag that precedes a command string to execute (in this case, our *regular expression*).
   - As for the `regex`:

     1. `s` means means we’re performing a substitution (as in `s/<pattern>/<replacement>/<modifier(s)>`)
     2. `/<pattern>` represents what we’re looking for:

        1. `\n\s+` means looks for any *new-lines* followed by **one** or **more** *spaces*.
        2. `(?=\w)` means the last space must precede an alphanumeric character; but, that character should not be included in the match.
     3. `/<replacement>` is what we want to substitute the match with:

        1. `,` will replace any *new-lin*e followed by **one** or **more** *spaces* that precede an *alphanumeric* character with a *comma*.
     4. `/<modifier(s)>` are optional flags that determine anything from how the pattern is matched, to how the substitution should work:

        1. `g` means *global-match*. By default, `regex` will only match the **first occurrence**; *global* tells it to match/replace **all occurrences**.
2. The second `grep` grabs whatever line starts with `brlan0`:

   1. `^` means search the beginning of each line.
   2. `brlan0` is the bridge you’re looking for.
   3. `\b` means this is a *word-boundary*; as in, no other alphanumeric characters should follow the preceding text.
3. Lastly, the `awk` statement will print the interfaces at the end of the line.

   1. `awk` uses *field-separators* to process text as columns separated
      by a delimiter.
   2. By default, text is delimited by any number of
      *spaces*.
   3. `{}` are just standard enclosures for line processing.
   4. `print` is a function that prints whatever value you give it.
   5. `$NF` is a `builtin` variable that always refers to the last *column* (aka *field*)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it looks like that "-zop" is not supported in my customized linux...

Comment: @RickSanchez, I’ve updated my answer. Hopefully that works for you.